# not working combobox in IE8

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I used tje following code to populate a combobox with data. It works in Firefox and Google Chrome but not in IE8.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", url:"reg/data/data.php", 
    data: {
        cat:"Y",
        //toUser: "4",
        // ignoreMessages:"1
    },
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
            $('#catogery').append( new Option(elem.id) );
            //console.log(elem);
        });              
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT CATCODE from subjectmaster");

$messages;

header('Content-type: application/json');

$return_arr = array(); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row_array['id']=$row[0];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: i uncomment it but is still the same as before.why it happens only in IE

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma from after the cat:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST", url:"reg/data/data.php", 
data: {
    cat:"Y"

},
success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
        $('#catogery').append( new Option(elem.id) );
        //console.log(elem);
    });              
}
```

});

Comment: what will happen if i call the php file without using the cat variable

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned "," in data array and there is no element after that. Remove "," and it should work.

```
data: {
   cat:"Y", //<------Remove this comma
   //toUser: "4",
   // ignoreMessages:"1
}
```